# SQL Server query for dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a main table with two columns start_date and End_date and I need to join to Date dim table and has two columns as start_date and end_date. But I am not able to get the expected results.

For some the records I am getting duplicate results.

Can anyone please help?

Main table:

[image]

Date table:

[image]

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Inv_Crd_key,
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Customer_Key, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Period_Key, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Product_Key, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.SalesPerson_Key, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Inv_Crd_No, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Your_Ref,
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Alt_Ref, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Order_No, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Bid_No, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Creator, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Support_Start_Date,
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Support_End_Date,
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.MLA_Number,
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.New_Renew_Cancelled, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Qty,
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Unit_Price, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Total_Value, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Cost, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Cogs_Adj, 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Margin,
    Period_Ref_Start.Year_Num as Start_Year,
    Period_Ref_Start.Month_Num as Start_Month,
    Period_Ref_Start.Period_Key as Supp_start_key,
    Period_Ref_End.Year_Num as End_Year,
    Period_Ref_End.Month_Num as End_Month,
    Period_Ref_End.Period_Key as Supp_end_key,
    Invoice_credit_fact.description
FROM
    Invoice_Credit_Fact,
    Product_Ref,
    Period_Ref Period_Ref_Start,
    Period_Ref Period_Ref_End
WHERE 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Product_Key = Product_Ref.Product_Key   
    AND DATEADD(day, 5, ISNULL(Invoice_Credit_Fact.Support_Start_Date, '9999-01-01')) 
            BETWEEN Period_Ref_Start.Start_Date AND Period_Ref_Start.End_Date
    AND DATEADD(day, -5, ISNULL(Invoice_Credit_Fact.Support_End_Date, '9999-01-01')) 
            BETWEEN Period_Ref_End.Start_Date AND Period_Ref_End.End_Date
ORDER BY 
    Invoice_Credit_Fact.Inv_Crd_No
```

Results contains duplicate rows. Please tell me how to eliminate the duplicates in the query

[image]

Comment: Try using JOINS instead of comma list in your FROM clause.

Comment: You have support periods that span over multiple months, so these rows are duplicated. I would call that a feature rather than a bug. Other than that, you should be showing the results that you are getting, and explain what you think is wrong.

Comment: FROM         
Invoice_Credit_Fact 
INNER JOIN Product_Ref ON Invoice_Credit_Fact.Product_Key = Product_Ref.Product_Key 
CROSS JOIN Period_Ref AS Period_Ref_Start 
CROSS JOIN Period_Ref AS Period_Ref_End
WHERE     
Invoice_Credit_Fact.Inv_Crd_No IN ('SIN020808')
AND (DATEADD(day, 5, ISNULL(Invoice_Credit_Fact.Support_Start_Date, '9999-01-01')) BETWEEN Period_Ref_Start.Start_Date AND Period_Ref_Start.End_Date) 
AND (DATEADD(day, - 5, ISNULL(Invoice_Credit_Fact.Support_End_Date, '9999-01-01')) BETWEEN Period_Ref_End.Start_Date AND Period_Ref_End.End_Date)

Comment: changed the query to join condition but still getting the duplicates. Can you please tell me how to eliminate the duplicates

Comment: Thanks Eric, here is the place where we can ask help and at one point situation every one will stuck and needs help. But thanks for your reply

Comment: These are **NOT** duplicates - `DISTINCT` prevents "real" duplicates! The columns `End_Month`  and `Supp_End_Key` are **different** in each row.....

Comment: Is it possible that your "date" table (Period_Ref - which is really a table of MONTHS not dates) has no row that will match the date of '9999-01-01'? If so, simplify your life and your code and make it easier to read and understand. Just remove those isnull expressions since those rows will be removed from your resultsets without that extra logic. Is it even valid for your table to have NULL values for Support_Start_Date and Support_End_Date?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicate data, because in the Maintable the column `SUPPORT_START_DATE` is the `Star_date` in the second table, and both of them you can join them by `PERIOD_KEY`

Comment: Hi Aladin, I tried joining them with Period_key but not getting the results. I have edited the original post and included the results. Can you please take a look and help me?